# Phpunit, Как сделать запрос к бд?

Tags: php, phpunit

Есть тесты, которые выполняются и записывают некоторые данные в бд.
Есть метод в конце, который должен сделать запрос в бд и вытащить данные.
Как сделать запрос в бд?

```
public function testBdData(){
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать запрос в бд как обычно :-)

Comment: https://wiki.pwodev.com/php-connect-mysql/